# Finding a string *and* its substrings in a haystack

Tags: regex, string, substring

Suppose you have a string (e.g. `needle`). Its 19 continuous substrings are:

```
needle
needl eedle
need eedl edle
nee eed edl dle
ne ee ed dl le
n e d l
```

If I were to build a regex to match, in a haystack, any of the substrings I could simply do:

```
/(needle|needl|eedle|need|eedl|edle|nee|eed|edl|dle|ne|ee|ed|dl|le|n|e|d|l)/
```

but it doesn't look really elegant. Is there a better way to create a regex that will greedly match any one of the substrings of a given string?

Additionally, what if I posed another constraint, wanted to match only substrings longer than a threshold, e.g. for substrings of at least 3 characters:

```
/(needle|needl|eedle|need|eedl|edle|nee|eed|edl|dle)/
```

note: I deliberately did not mention any particular regex dialect. Please state which one you're using in your answer.

Comment: This looks very much like the [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) problem. Does it need to be regexp?

Comment: The length of the needle will surely be orders of magnitude smaller than that of the haystack. Moreover, I'm interested in knowing how many occurrences of any of the substrings of the needle appear in the haystack, not which one is the LCS.

Comment: i do not think that event far simplier question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114402/regexp-finding-longest-common-prefix-of-two-strings) has easy solution using one regexp so probably you should be more specific on what you really need. Can we generate the regexp programatically? Deos it need to be regexp?

Comment: @gorn Sure you can build it programatically (as some of the answers already imply) and no, it doesn't *really* have to be a regex (what I really need is simply to *count how many characters in the haystack belong to **at least one** of the substrings*) but I started wondering how to do with a regex, wasn't able to, and thought it could make for a good SO question.

Comment: Do you realize that "belongs to at least one substring of *at least* length n" ist the same as "belongs to at least one substring of *exactly* length n"? It's really easy programmatically that way, but I can't do it with a regex.

Comment: @WolframH I already solved it in another way *without* using regexes. This question, though, is about solving the problem *using* regexes. Put in another way, this question is purely academic.

Answer (score 4):

As Qtax suggested, the expression

`n(e(e(d(l(e)?)?)?)?)?|e(e(d(l(e)?)?)?)?|e(d(l(e)?)?)?|d(l(e)?)?|l(e)?|e`

would be the way to go if you wanted to write an explicit regular expression (`egrep` syntax, optionally replace `(...)` by `(?:...)`). The reason why this is better than the initial solution is that the condensed version requires only O(n^2) space compared to O(n^3) space in the original version, where `n` is the length of the input. Try this with `extraordinarily` as input to see the difference. I guess the condensed version is also faster with many regexp engines out there.

The expression

`nee(d(l(e)?)?)?|eed(l(e)?)?|edl(e)?|dle`

will look for substrings of length 3 or longer.

As pointed out by vhallac, the generated regular expressions are a bit redundant and can be optimized. Apart from the proposed Emacs tool, there is a Perl package [Regexp::Optimizer](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Regexp-Optimizer-0.15/lib/Regexp/Optimizer.pm) that I hoped would help here, but a quick check failed for the first regular expression.

Note that many regexp engines perform non-overlapping search by default. Check this with the requirements of your problem.

Comment: Emacs' `regexp-opt` generates slightly shorter regexps: `(dle?|e(dle?|ed(le?)?|[de])|le|ne(e(d(le?)?)?)?|[deln])` and `(dle|e(dle?|ed(le?)?)|nee(?:d(?:le?)?)?)`

Comment: Is this bundled in a library so it can be used from outside Emacs?

Comment: Oops. I forgot to remove a few `?:`s on the second: `(dle|e(dle?|ed(le?)?)|nee(d(le?)?)?)`

Comment: Source is available, but it is in elisp. So you're probably better off just invoking emacs in batch mode to generate these strings. Alternatively, you can reverse engineer and reimplement in another language.

Comment: If you want to have a look: http://www.koders.com/lisp/fid89EE76D0B9B838331665FD4D15EED607512EA8EA.aspx?s=regexp-opt.el#L1

Answer (score 3):

I have found elegant *almostsolution*, depending how badly you need only one regexp. For example here is the regexp, which finds common substring (perl) of length 7:

```
"$needle\0$heystack" =~ /(.{7}).*?\0.*\1/s
```

Matching string is in **\1**. Strings should not contain null character which is used as separator.

You should make a cycle which starters  with length of the needle and goes downto treshold and tries to match the regexp.

Comment: Elegant! How about the run time?

Comment: Very impressive. One question, though: wouldn't it match, say, "ee ed" (or in general consecutive short strings in your haystack)?

Comment: @vhallac: Sorry I do not see why it would do that - then \0 serves as as separator. It should not be in neither strings.

Comment: Aha, I misunderstood your solution. For some reason I thought $needle would contain all the substrings. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to create a regex that will match any one of the
>   substrings of a given string?

No. But you can generate such expression easily.

Comment: Will your regex `n(?:e(?:e(?:d(?:l(?:e?)?)?)?)?)?` match the substring `e`? It doesn't look like it will.

Comment: It will not, that was just an example of part of the complete expression which would contain several of these.

Comment: Then that's even less elegant than my solution, isn't it?

Comment: And that's what I said in my answer.

Comment: + No. That's not really what Regex does.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you're just looking for
`.*(.{1,6}).*`

Comment: PS I don't see why you didn't include duplicate sub-strings. This will include them so you'll have to take care of them programatically, for example by using a hash set.

Comment: this will match *anything*... I don't see how your answer is related to my question...

Comment: It will match all the sub-strings in a string. Or am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: CAFxX asked for a match of all substrings of `needle` in another, bigger text.