# Regexp finding longest common prefix of two strings

Tags: python, ruby, regex, perl, replace

Is there a regexp which would find longest common prefix of two strings? And if this is not solvable by one regexp, what would be the most elegant piece of code or oneliner using regexp (perl, ruby, python, anything).

PS: I can do this easily programatically, I am asking rather for curiosity, because it seems to me that this could be solveable by regexp.

PPS: Extra bonus for O(n) solution using regexps. Come on, it should exist!

Comment: I do not think it's possible. With REs, you see if a piece of data (string) matches an expression (the RE: a program if you will). You now have to pieces of data - neither is a (proper) RE. To find the longest common prefix, you need "something" that takes both as inputs... but REs don't do that: some glue is needed.

Comment: I am happy with a glue solution - maybe convert one of the strings to regexp and than use it on the second one ...

Comment: Are the two strings random input or one of them has privileges? In the second case (for example the string is reused multiple times for the same matching) some optimisation would be worth to do.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475437/find-first-character-that-is-different-between-two-strings (PHP; not sure if it applies to Python too)

Comment: My solution below addresses the issue that Alien Life Form raises. You have two inputs and an output. Perl-style pseudo-regular expressions don't allow this. But a more general approach is possible.

Another issue that has oddly gone unmentioned, is that lcp is most commonly used in the context of suffix arrays, and in this context there are linear time algorithms for finding the complete lcp table.  The most well known is by Ko et al.

Comment: @Dale G. - I like you trying to analyse the task in general way, but I do not know lcp tables. Link? BTW - clearly the posted solution somehow deals with the fact that there are two imputs by creatively combining first and second in one inpot (not mentioning the excellent althought little bit non regexpish xor solution). Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If there's some character that neither string contains —, say, `\0` — you could write

```
"$first\0$second" =~ m/^(.*).*\0\1/s;
```

and the longest common prefix would be saved as `$1`.

---

**Edited to add:** This is obviously very inefficient. I think that if efficiency is a concern, then this simply isn't the approach we should be using; but we can at least improve it by changing `.*` to `[^\0]*` to prevent useless greediness that will just have to be backtracked again, and wrapping the second `[^\0]*` in `(?>…)` to prevent backtracking that can't help. This:

```
"$first\0$second" =~ m/^([^\0]*)(?>[^\0]*)\0\1/s;
```

This will yield the same result, but much more efficiently. (But still not nearly *as* efficiently as a straightforward non–regex-based approach. If the strings both have length *n*, I'd expect its worst case to take at least O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time, whereas the straightforward non–regex-based approach would take O(*n*) time in *its* worst case.)

Comment: wow, great idea - it's so simple, i did not thought about joining them. I do not fully understand why it would match the longest part, but I am going to think about it :-)

Comment: +1: Clever but expensive.  An RE is not the way to solve the problem, even though this achieves the result - subject to the regexes accepting the null embedded in the string.  (That's not a fatal objection; you can use any character sequence that doesn't appear in either string as the separator.)

Comment: expensive - agree, but that is fine. I asked for elegant, not fast.

Comment: BTW - how expensive that REALLY is? the separator helps the backtracking engine work quite efficiently so is not it just O(string lentgth)?

Comment: For rubyist:

`(/^(.*).*\0\1/s).match(first+"\0"+second).to_a[1]`

Comment: HEY - I have found nice generalization for an array of strings: `array.join("\0") =~ /^(.*).*(\0\1[^\0]*)$/s`

Comment: @gorn: I've edited my answer to give a more efficient version -- but it's still probably on the order of *n*-squared, because each time the first string has to be re-backtracked, the `\1` part has to be re-matched in its entirety. That is -- suppose that the two strings have no common prefix at all. Then the regex has to try every single prefix of the first string and see if the second string starts with it. Merely checking the prefix is already O(*n*) time, and it needs to be done *n* times.

Comment: Optimization: it can be worth exchanging `$first` with `$second` if `$first` is longer than `$second`.

Comment: @ruakh - I do not think that the O(n2) argument is correct in practice - if they do not have the common prefix the checking of \1 after the \0 separator always fails at the first character. In fact the shorter the prefix is the faster the lookup is. The problem has nice strange properties - if you would be able to start with short string and extend it (in  \1) than you basically use the obvious programatical solution. However regexp works exactly the opposite way - it tries the longest and makes it shorter and shorter.

Comment: @gorn: "if they do not have the common prefix the checking of \1 after the \0 separator always fails at the first character": Oh, good point. But the worst case is still at least O(n²): suppose that the strings both have length *n*, and their common prefix has length n/2. Then you have to try n/2 possible `\1`s, and each try examines n/2 characters before it fails. O(n²/4) = O(n²).

Comment: BTW after ginwnig it a thought I think there must be O(n) solution using regexps. I have edited my question to mention it.

Comment: @rukah: I have found IT! It is O(n) - look at my anwer below. Copy it to your accepted answer if you want, as the inspiration comes from you.

Comment: @rukah: I have found another "nearly" linear solution - check it - it looks nice :-)

Answer (score 19):

Here's a Python one-liner:

```
>>> a = 'stackoverflow'
>>> b = 'stackofpancakes'
>>> a[:[x[0]==x[1] for x in zip(a,b)].index(0)]
0: 'stacko'
>>> a = 'nothing in'
>>> b = 'common'
>>> a[:[x[0]==x[1] for x in zip(a,b)].index(0)]
1: ''
>>>
```

Comment: Cute.  What's the `0:` and `1:` in the interpreter results?  Are you using some kind of enhanced Python shell that numbers the outputs or something?

Comment: Stack-O: A stunt programmer. Likes to practice extreme programming.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not handle the case, where `a` is a prefix of `b` like: `a, b = 'test', 'testing'`. It will throw a `ValueError` because `0` will not be inside a list.

Comment: @DawidFatyga: yeah, but that's easily fixed:
```a[:([x[0]==x[1] for x in zip(a,b)]+[0]).index(0)]```

Comment: Although this looks nice I asked for regexp solution, so this does not aplly here.

Answer (score 15):

Here's one fairly efficient way which uses a regexp.  The code is in Perl, but the principle should be adaptable to other languages:

```
my $xor = "$first" ^ "$second";    # quotes force string xor even for numbers
$xor =~ /^\0*/;                    # match leading null characters
my $common_prefix_length = $+[0];  # get length of match
```

(A subtlety worth noting  is that Perl's string XOR operator (`^`) in effect pads the shorter string with nulls to match the length of the longer one.  Thus, if the strings might contain null characters, *and* if the shorter string happens to be a prefix of the longer one, the common prefix length calculated with this code might exceed the length of the shorter string.)

Comment: Very nice trick! I did not find short elegant way to do string xor in ruby thought.

Comment: `sub LCP
{
    my $match = shift;
    for (@_)
    {
        ($match ^ $_) =~ /^\0*/;
        substr($match, $+[0]) = '';
    }
    $match;
}` https://gist.github.com/3309172

Answer (score 8):

simple and efficient

```
def common_prefix(a,b):
  i = 0
  for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
    if x!=y: break
  return a[:i]
```

Comment: Unless `a` and `b` are big enough so that `a+b` does not fit into the memory ;-) `itertools.izip` is a better alternative here.

Comment: Does not properly handle the case where `a` is a prefix of `b` (e.g., "FooBar" and "Foo" results in "Fo".

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're going to have is that a regular expression matches against one string at a time so isn't intended for comparing two strings.

If there's a character that you can be sure isn't in either string you can use it separate them in a single string and then search using back references to groups.

So in the example below I'm using whitespace as the separator

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile("(?P<prefix>\S*)\S*\s+(?P=prefix)")
>>> pattern.match("stack stable").group('prefix')
'sta'
>>> pattern.match("123456 12345").group('prefix')
'12345'
```

Comment: Yes this is nice answer. I have already accepted another one with the same base idea, but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another attempt for O(n) solution:

```
$x=length($first); $_="$first\0$second"; s/((.)(?!.{$x}\2)).*//s;
```

it depends whether .{n} is considered O(1) or O(n), I do not know how efficiently this is implemented.

*Notes: 1. \0 should not be in either string it is used as delimiter 2. result is in $_*

Comment: it can be optimized, but this is the main idea inobscured

Comment: +1, clever! Though, a tiny point: you need to add `/s` (both for correctness and for it to even be conceivable that `.{n}` is O(1) -- without the `/s`, `.{n}` would at least have to scan for newlines, unless the regex engine does some sort of pre-check to make sure there aren't any anyway). And you can drop the `/g`, though I suppose it's not harmful.

Comment: yes, sorry, there should have been s instead of g, corrected. All in all it seems that it have lots of interesting solutions :-) ... One of my really crazy ideas was to invert one of the strings, and than eat doubled characters from the middle :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an O(N) solution with Foma-like pseudocode regular expressions over triples (for lcp, you have two inputs and an output). To keep it simple, I assume a binary alphabet {a,b}:

```
def match {a:a:a, b:b:b};
def mismatch {a:b:ε, b:a:ε};
def lcp match* ∪ (match* mismatch (Σ:Σ:ε)*)
```

Now you just need a language that implements multi-tape transducers.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Essentially this is what the question calls for, and I believe that most of the other answers are trying to hack a 3-tape transducer without giving the device a name. Once you have a name, it's possible to find various implementations in various languages. And you can find papers on closure and decidability properties, etc

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by ruakh's answer, here is the O(n) regexp solution:

```
"$first \0$second" =~ m/^(.*?)(.).*\0\1(?!\2)/s;
```

*Notes:
 1. neither string contains \0
 2. longest common prefix would be saved as $1
 3. the space is important!*

**Edit:** well it is not correct as rukach metions, but the idea is correct, but we should push regexp machine not to check the beginning letters repeatedly. The basic idea can be also rewritten in this perl oneliner.

```
perl -e ' $_="$first\0$second\n"; while(s/^(.)(.*?)\0\1/\2\0/gs) {print $1;}; '
```

I wonder if it can be incorporated back into regexp solution.

Comment: That's still at least O(n²). The worst-case time occurs when `$first` and `$second` are identical: the engine then needs to test every single prefix of `$first`. If a prefix has length *m*, then testing for it is at least O(m), so the worst-case time is at least O(0+1+2+...+n), which is O(n²).

Comment: (Also, that would misbehave slightly if `$second` starts with `$first` followed by a space, since then `\2` would always match, so `(?!\2)` would never succeed. But that's remediable either by using `\0` again instead of a space -- since, by assumption, `$second` doesn't contain `\0` -- or else by saying that the longest common prefix is `$1 // $first` rather than simply `$1`.)

Comment: It is true that i did not count with the fact, that the prefix as it gets longer gets rechecked everytime from beginning. But it should not be necessary - it can just check the letters which it is adding, but I do not know how to put it in one regexp.

Comment: (No, you are not right, and Yes the cornercase is annoying :-) The double \0's, did not work when I tried it fast, so i introduced the space, which works I believe. If the `$second` starts with `$first` and space, than if would not match, because if \2 eats \0 and the \0 can not match. )

Comment: (Yeah, with `\0\0` you need to tweak it a bit further, because otherwise the `(.*?)` can have length zero, and the `\0\1(?!\2)` will then match the first `\0`, because `(?=\0)` implies `(?!\2)`. I think that changing `\0\1(?!\2)` to `\0(?!\0)\1(?!\2)` would suffice.)

Comment: (Good idea, but still, the solution with anything else (i.e. space) works as well, it just ignores last character before \0 but it should be there)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7300/discussion-between-gorn-and-ruakh)

Answer (score 1):

Could be useful in some *remote* cases so here it goes:

RegEx only solution in 3 steps (*couldn't create a RegEx in one go*):

String A: `abcdef`
String B: `abcxef`

- 1st pass: create RegEx from `String A` *(part 1)*:
  Match: `/(.)/g`
  Replace: `\1(`
  Result: `a(b(c(d(e(f(`
  Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/aJ4pY7
- 2nd pass: create RegEx from `1st pass result`
  Match: `/^(.\()(?=(.*)$)|\G.\(/g`
  Replace: `\1\2)?+`
  Result: `a(b(c(d(e(f()?+)?+)?+)?+)?+)?+`
  Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/xJ7bK7
- 3rd pass: test `String B` against RegEx created in `2nd pass`
  Match: `/a(b(c(d(e(f()?+)?+)?+)?+)?+)?+/`
  Result: `abc` ([explained demo](http://regex101.com/r/hU8qG2))

And here's the *glorified* **one-liner** in PHP:

```
preg_match('/^'.preg_replace('/^(.\()(?=(.*)$)|\G.\(/','\1\2)?+',preg_replace('/(.)/','\1(',$a)).'/',$b,$longest);
```

Code live at: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dCrqLa

Comment: I must admit that althought it is little bit "bruteforce", it has some kind of elegancy at the same time. Thanks for this, especially I like the second step with positive lookahead regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Non regexp, non duplicating string at each iteration solution:

```
def common_prefix(a, b):
   #sort strings so that we loop on the shorter one
   a, b = sorted((a,b), key=len)
   for index, letter in a:
      if letter != b[index]:
          return a[:index - 1]
   return a
```

Comment: Thanks for nice clean code. However, I was rather looking for regexp solution purely for menthal exercise, in this case the kind of solution you are suggesting is probably more pracctical. However some of the answers are very creative ...

Answer (score 0):

I second ruakh's answer for the regexp (with my suggested optimization in the comments). Simple to write, but not simple and efficient to run if the first string is long.

Here is an efficient, non-regexp, readable, one-line answer:

```
$ perl -E '($n,$l)=(0,length $ARGV[0]); while ($n < $l) { $s = substr($ARGV[0], $n, 1); last if $s ne substr($ARGV[1], $n, 1); $n++ } say substr($ARGV[0], 0, $n)' abce abcdef
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using extended regular expressions as in Foma or Xfst.

```
def range(x) x.l;
def longest(L) L - range(range(L ∘ [[Σ:ε]+ [Σ:a]*]) ∘ [a:Σ]*); 
def prefix(W) range(W ∘ [Σ* Σ*:ε]);
def lcp(A,B) longest(prefix(A) ∩ prefix(B));
```

The hardest part here is to define "longest". Generally speaking, to
optimize, you construct the set of non–optimal strings (worsening) and
then remove these (filtering).

This is really a purist approach, which avoids non-regular operations
such a capturing.

Answer (score 0):

```
string1=input()
string2=input()
string1=string1.lower()
string2=string2.lower()
l1=len(string1)
l2=len(string2)
min_len=min(l1,l2)
for i in range(min_len):
    if string1[i]!=string2[i]:
        break
if i==0:
    print(-1)
else:
    print(string2[:i])
```

Comment: Where is the regex?

Answer (score -1):

I have the idea this is most inefficient. No err checking, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my($s1,$s2)=(@ARGV);
#find the shortest string put it into s1, if you will.

my $n=0;
my $reg;

foreach my $c (split(//,$s1)) { $reg .="($c"; $n++;}

$reg .= ")?" x $n;

$s2 =~ /$reg/; 

print $&,"\n";
```

Comment: 1) the OP specifically asked for a regexp based solution. 2) see the first comment in my code, I could not be bothered to write the code to do that; 3) reading TFQ seldom hurts.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution I implemented for a leetcode problem:

```
def max_len(strs):
    """
    :type strs: List[str]
    :rtype: int
    """
    min_s = len(strs[0]);
    for s in strs:
        if (len(s) < min_s):
            min_s = len(s);
    return min_s;


class Solution2:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs):
    """
    :type strs: List[str]
    :rtype: str
    """
    acc = -1;
    test_len = max_len(strs);
    for i in range(test_len):
        t = strs[0][i];
        acc2 = 0;
        for j in range(len(strs)):
            if (strs[j][i] == t):
                acc2 += 1;
        if (acc2 == len(strs)):
            acc += 1;

    if (acc == -1):
        return ""
    else:
        return strs[0][:acc + 1]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This does not use regexps as I formulated the original request, but thanks abyways.