# Regex that will match the longest possible substring of a string1 with the string2

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have two strings a and b with me. I want a regular expression pattern such it will match the longest possible substring of b with a from the beginning of a.

For example,

```
a = "aaaabaaa"
b = "aaazb"
answer_i_need = "aaa"
```

example 2,

```
a = "aaaabaaa"
b = "aaaa"
answer_i_need = "aaaa"
```

example 2,

```
a = "aaaabaaa"
b = "baaa"
answer_i_need = ""
```

I know the option of finding all substrings of b and check whether it matches with a, but it will take too long as the strings are very very long and I am using Python.
To be honest I am not sure whether it is possible, anyway I would be very thankful if I could find one such a solution.

Edit: In  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114402/regexp-finding-longest-common-prefix-of-two-strings/)  the OP needs an elegant answer, while I am dealing with very long strings( almost 100,000 characters) , so I would like to know the most efficient answer possible.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't come across that question,let me read it and reply..

Comment: @DSM to be honest, I didn't find the answer I as looking for in that link because the OP needs an elegant answer while I need an efficient one. So most of the answers posted there weren't clear on how they efficient they are.

Comment: @coding_pleasures So look at those answers, and test them yourself to see which is fastest on _your_ data.  If we all test it for you, we might get different results in different cases.

Comment: @DSM your answer os.path.commonprefix() was perfect for my needs.

Comment: Fine idea to use ``os.path.commonprefix()``, I didn't know its existence. However, according to tests I did on two strings of length 1`000 and 4`720`000, ``commonprefix()`` takes around 15% more time to execute than my solution. I suppose you say that it fulfills your needs for other reason than efficiency.

Comment: @eyquem Thanks for taking the time to test it. Because of your comment, I did my own tests again and I was getting almost the same time for both of the solutions. I am sorry for calling your solution inefficient. Unfortunately, both didn't meet my needs.

Comment: I'm not annoyed if a solution written by me is not good. I just like to understand things. How did you test ? I tested with ``time.clock()``, it's plenty enough according to me, I no more use ``timeit``, and I got 15% more execution time with ``commonprefix()``

Comment: So you still hasn't find a better solution to improve your code, while other solutions given in the challenge are better, am I right ? Maybe, the efficiency of your code could be unsufficient because all the other parts in your code, not only because of the snippet that must find a common beginning for two strings.

Comment: I'm impressed by your interest in helping me :) Lemme introduce my problem  which is this-> http://pastebin.com/gqSMSyih . The solution I wrote with common prefix is this -> http://pastebin.com/ddLcWE8E .And with your function -> http://pastebin.com/G4CX0aRL .Both give me a running time of 30s while my requirement is to complete it by 16 seconds.

Comment: while the input I used for both programs is this -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/2x4scbtkyrblo8e/input.txt

Answer (score 1):

I think your are complicating things. I love regexes but I don't find we must try to use them for tasks they aren't fitted to.

Your problem is easy solved like follows:

```
import re


def longest_common_beginning(a,b):
    i = 0
    for i in xrange(min(len(a),len(b))):
        if a[i]!=b[i]:
            return a[:i]
    else:
        return a[:i+1]

for a,b,ain in (("aaaabaaa","aaazb","aaa"),
                ("aaaabaaa","aaaa", "aaaa"),
                ("aaaabaaa","baaa","")):
    x = longest_common_beginning(a,b)  
    print ('a   : %r\n'
           'b   : %r\n'
           'ain : %r\n'
           'x   : %r   ain==x is %s\n'
           % (a,b,ain,x,ain==x))
```

`i=0` is needed for the cases in which one of **a** or **b** is an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately this answer is little too inefficient when the strings become very long( about 100,000 char long). That's why I was hoping regex might help me in this regard.

Comment: I think regexes are completely out of subject for the problem. And I have no other idea, not only how faster, but even how differently from my code it could be done. I've just tried to use enumerate() or izip() in my code, but it's slower. I'm eager to see someone to propose a better solution than me. The only possibility that remains, in my opinion, is to code the function in C

Comment: As @eyquem says, I don't think you'll improve performance by using a regex here. For a regex to solve this, it will have to do a lot of backtracking. A simple loop like the one above seems like the best choice.

Comment: The thread mentioned by @DSM shows a nice regex solution to this. You will code less, but it will be much slower than a simple loop like the one above.

Comment: @Francis Yes, I've read the answers in the cited thread, and they say that their solutions are not efficient. So I think one must not wait more after a better magical solution using regex.

Comment: @eyquem Thank you for your suggestions. I have asked this question to solve a section of a programming challenge where my present code using the simple loop has proved to be inefficient. After viewing highest scores of that problem, I was convinced there was a better and efficient solution of solving it. This situation leaves me hopeless :(