# perl: how to make compact name from a numbered sequence

Tags: perl, sequence, names

[perl 5.8.8]

I have a sequence of names of things like:

```
names='foobar1304,foobar1305,foobar1306,foobar1307'
```

where the names differ only by a contiguous string of digits somewhere in the name.  The strings of digits in any sequence are all of the same length, and the digit strings form a continuous numeric sequence with no skips, e.g. `003,004,005`.

I want a compact representation like:

```
compact_name='foobar1304-7'
```

(The compact form is just a name, so it's exact form is negotiable.)
There will usually only be <10 things, though some sets might span a decade, e.g.

```
'foobaz2205-11'
```

Is there some concise way to do this in perl?  I'm not a big perl hacker, so be a little gentle...

Bonus points for handling embedded sequences like:

```
names='foobar33-pqq,foobar34-pqq,foobar35-pqq'
```

The ideal script would neatly fall back to `'firstname2301-lastname9922'` in case it can't identify a sequence in the names.

Comment: This question is under-specified.  You need to come up with a set of rules that handles all possible inputs.  For your last example, the implied simplification `foobar33-35-pqq` might turn out to be ambiguous in context.  The basic idea of extracting the number and collapsing sequences is pretty simple given Perl's regex capabilites, but your bigger issue is deciding what you actually want to do.

Comment: fixed, I think.  I don't see the ambiguity in `foobar33-35-pqq` .  Note I specified differences are '**a** contiguous string of digits'.  If there's more than one string of digits in the name, then I'll just bail.

Comment: I think what you want is to split the string into an array (`@list = split(",", $names)` or something similar), then find the [longest common prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114402/regexp-finding-longest-common-prefix-of-two-strings) of those words in the array. Bonus points for finding the longest common suffix. So you separate the words into prefix, variable part, and suffix. Then your answer is "$prefix$varFirst" . "-" . "$varLast$suffix". Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I got your specification, but it works somehow:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More;

sub compact {
    my $string = shift;
    my ($name, $value) = split /=/, $string;

    $name =~ s/s$// or die "Cannot create compact name for $name.\n";  #/ SO hilite bug
    $name = 'compact_' . $name;

    $value =~ s/^'|'$//g;                                              #/ SO hilite bug
    my @values = split /,/, $value;                                    #/ SO hilite bug
    my ($prefix, $first, $suffix) = $values[0] =~ /^(.+?)([0-9]+)(.*)$/;

    my $last = $first + $#values;
    my $same = 0;
    $same++ while substr($first, 0, $same) eq substr($last, 0, $same);
    $last = substr $last, $same - 1;

    for my $i ($first .. $first + $#values) {
        $values[$i - $first] eq ($prefix . $i . $suffix) 
            or die "Invalid sequence at $values[$i-$first].\n";
    }
    return "$name='$prefix$first-$last$suffix'";
}


is( compact("names='foobar1304,foobar1305,foobar1306,foobar1307'"),
    "compact_name='foobar1304-7'");

is( compact("names='foobaz2205,foobaz2206,foobaz2207,foobaz2208,foobaz2209,foobaz2210,foobaz2211'"),
    "compact_name='foobaz2205-11'");

is( compact("names='foobar33-pqq,foobar34-pqq,foobar35-pqq'"),
    "compact_name='foobar33-5-pqq'");

done_testing();
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone sure will post an more elegant solution, but the following

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $names='foobar1308-xy,foobar1309-xy,foobar1310-xy,foobar1311-xy';
my @names = split /,/,$names;

my $pfx = lcp(@names);

my @nums = map { m/$pfx(\d*)/; $1 } @names;
my $first=shift @nums;
my $last = pop @nums;
my $suf=$names[0];
$suf =~ s/$pfx\d*//;

print "$pfx\{$first-$last}$suf\n";

#https://gist.github.com/3309172
sub lcp {
    my $match = shift;
    substr($match, (($match ^ $_) =~ /^\0*/, $+[0])) = '' for @_;
    $match;
}
```

prints:

```
foobar13{08-11}-xy
```