# Concatenate strings if they have an overlapping region

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am trying to write a script that will find strings that share an overlapping region of 5 letters at the beginning or end of each string (shown in example below).

```
facgakfjeakfjekfzpgghi
                 pgghiaewkfjaekfjkjakjfkj
                                    kjfkjaejfaefkajewf
```

I am trying to create a new string which concatenates all three, so the output would be:

```
facgakfjeakfjekfzpgghiaewkfjaekfjkjakjfkjaejfaefkajewf
```

Edit:

This is the input:

```
x = ('facgakfjeakfjekfzpgghi', 'kjfkjaejfaefkajewf', 'pgghiaewkfjaekfjkjakjfkj')
```

**the list is not ordered

What I've written so far *but is not correct:

```
def findOverlap(seq)
    i = 0
    while i < len(seq): 
        for x[i]:
        #check if x[0:5] == [:5] elsewhere

 x = ('facgakfjeakfjekfzpgghi', 'kjfkjaejfaefkajewf', 'pgghiaewkfjaekfjkjakjfkj')
findOverlap(x)
```

Comment: show your input please

Comment: @RomanPekar, ok I edited it to show input

Comment: zpgghi is a 6 letter string, do you mean 'overlapping region of 5 or more letters'?

Comment: And `kjfjj` doesn't match `kjfkj`

Comment: @RomanPekar these were both typos. Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: @user2767074 so `x[1]` is also typoed then? How are you typoing these - why aren't you copy pasting from a source file or something? :P

Comment: Which string is the the first? Which string to choose if there are several strings that have same prefix as suffix of the current? Can you provide example which includes such cases?

Comment: Will `x` always have 3 elements or is `x` a function that takes any number of arguments and combines them?

Comment: And did you try anything toward solving the problem? Show us some code

Comment: @RobertLujo, there should never be more than one match for the purposes of what I'm doing. Additionally, the string that has a prefix that does not match the suffix of another is the first.

Comment: @JWarner112 x will always have 3 elements

Comment: Please give us a snippet of the code you've worked on so far; Context will work best. For instance, if you are dealing with simply raw strings, this example you've given works; But if you're dealing with, say, filenames/paths, os.path has a lot of string manipulators that work adeptly. Since we don't know exactly _how_ you plan to use the code, our help is generalized and guesswork at best.

Comment: @JWarner112 I've added some code that shows my current through process, but may not really be very helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a dictionary mapping the first 5 characters of each string to its tail

```
strings = {s[:5]: s[5:] for s in x}
```

and a set of all the suffixes:

```
suffixes = set(s[-5:] for s in x)
```

Now find the string whose prefix does not match any suffix:

```
prefix = next(p for p in strings if p not in suffixes)
```

Now we can follow the chain of strings:

```
result = [prefix]
while prefix in strings:
    result.append(strings[prefix])
    prefix = strings[prefix][-5:]
print "".join(result)
```

Comment: nice one, +1. I was thinking about getting prefixes and suffixes, sorting it and then chain, but this one is better

Comment: @user3358205: The input list `x` can consist of any number of strings.

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force approach - do all combinations and return the first that matches linking terms:

```
def solution(x):
    from itertools import permutations
    for perm in permutations(x):
        linked = [perm[i][:-5] for i in range(len(perm)-1) 
                               if perm[i][-5:]==perm[i+1][:5]]
        if len(perm)-1==len(linked):
            return "".join(linked)+perm[-1]
    return None

x = ('facgakfjeakfjekfzpgghi', 'kjfkjaejfaefkajewf', 'pgghiaewkfjaekfjkjakjfkj')
print solution(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop over each pair of candidates, reverse the second string and use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114402)

Comment: Why reverse the second string?